# Selection in Date Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

Now, I am working with asp.net , C# and I have made custom controls . In my custom controls especially in Date control, I want to select only month and day part in OnFocus Event.
Right Now, I have wrote

```
control.select();
```

then , as usual, the text of the control(2012/08/04) will be selected.

But now I want to give selection only on the part of the month and day(08/04). I am searching many ways  to do it. But I haven't got any ways until now. So I would like to know that Can I give a selection on only month and day part(08/24) of a Date Control.

With regards

Comment: what you are using in date control?

Comment: I used my custom control which is based on asp date control to show date.My problem is when Focusing in date control , I want to give a selection on month and day (08/24) not in (2012/08/24). It is just for display.  sorry for my poor English!.

Comment: It looks like you will need to write quite complicated code to select only month and day (it will involve javascript part). Please provide more information about your Date control, so that we can advise how to trigger custom selection for `OnFocus` event.